# How to use the board from Chess in Test?

Tags: java

So I'm creating a game and when I use board in the class Chess everything is okay but once I use it in another class it's telling me that board is null

Here are the simplified classes :

```
Chess

    public class Chess {
    public int[][] board;

    public int[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
    public void setBoard(int[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public Chess() {
        initialiseBoard();
    }
    private void initialiseBoard(){ // 1 = king, 2 = queen, 3 = knight, 4 = bishop , 5 = rook, 6 = pawn
        int[][] board = new int[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
            board[1][j - 1] = -6;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
            board[6][j - 1] = 6;
        }
        int[] Lblanc = {5,3,4,2,1,4,3,5};
        int[] Lnoir = {-5,-3,-4,-2,-1,-4,-3,-5};
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[0][j] = Lnoir[j];
            board[7][j] = Lblanc[j];
        }
        setBoard(board);
    }

    public void printBoard(){ //mettre private
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    public void play(){
        initialiseBoard();
        board[4][4] = 7;
        Test test = new Test();
        test.lol(); //print the board without the change
    }


}
```

Test

```
public class Test {
    Chess chess = new Chess();

    public void lol(){
        chess.printBoard();
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Chess chess = new Chess();
        chess.play();
    }
}
```

I suppose thats cause I created a new Chess(), but I don't know how to use the methods and attributes otherwise.

edit : the true play so just initialiseBoard in constructor doesn't work does it?

```
public void play() {
        while (true) {
            createPlayers();
            initialiseBoard();
            while (!isCheckMate()) {
                printBoard();
                Position[] move;
                do {
                    move = askMove();
                }
                while (!isValidMove(move,board));
                updateBoard(move);
                //switchPlayer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the behaviour you're expecting, but if you need board just for testing you should simply mimic the same behaviour you're having in your program. Initialise your board etc.

Comment: I need board to create a chess game so it's not just for testing 
the test was just to show you guys my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `initialiseBoard` method in `Chess` constructor:

```
public Chess() {
    initialiseBoard();
}
```

Or, you can call it right after the construction of `Chess` object:

```
Chess chess = new Chess();
chess.initialiseBoard();
```

You get a `null` because you never call this method.

Comment: I can't do that for every methods can I?
Like the Chess play(); is supposed to start a game of chess. 
I just put 1 method in it for the exemple
Added the true play whithout details

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: like the board value is modified everytime a player play so i can't use a constructor at the start

Comment: You still can use `initializeBoard` in constructor so there is no need for call of this method in `play(...)`

Comment: put it in the constructor and I still get null

Comment: Please edit your question with updated code. I launched your current code with `initializeBoard` in `Chess` constructor and `test.lol()` printed non-null value

Comment: Now the problem is that  test.lol() prints the board without the change, right?

Comment: exactly and if i need to put every change in the constructor what's the point of OOP

Comment: The problem is that in your `play` method you update a `board` field of `this` object  
But in `Test.lol()` method you print the board of  a *new* instance of `Chess` which you instantiated just in `Test` constructor, so you call `printBoard` method on a different object. To fix this, consider passing your `Chess` parameter through `Test` constructor rather than creating a new instance.

Comment: How would u do that? 
Would i be able to call the methods from chess in Test if I do that?
I knew creating a new instance was wrong, but didn't know how to do it differently.

Comment: you might wanna read the answer I posted 3 hours ago. you are doing it wrong. you can't instantiate a class inside itself.

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/nkrivenko/e51b5913cc848952a9c24742385283de

Comment: Seems legit but if i did it that way it's cause idk how to do it correctly.
Just started java so it may sounds like a stupid question

Comment: Updated my gist with `Test` constructor call

Comment: So u created an atribute chess in Test with a constructor to use the method from Chess and the Test t = new Test(this); take all the atributes values of Chess.
Is that it?

Comment: It takes all the attributes values of passed `Chess` object, yes

Comment: So I need to use a Test t = new Test(this); (just before using a method from chess in test) everytime i use a method from chess in test to have the latest values of the atributes? (edited)

Answer (score 0):

you are instantiating Test (which in turn instantiates Chess) inside Chess.play() which means you are making another instance of Chess inside Chess. now the second instance which is made inside Test has a separate board parameter that hasn't been initialized since the Test class does not call chess.play() in it so the initialiseBoard() is never called for Test class which means board is never initialized!
Now I'm not sure that's such a good idea...